# Pasar un objeto con queryParams en Router

Tags: angular, angular5

Tengo un array de objetos que reccoro con un ngFor. Posteriormente abajo tengo una barra de navegación en la que redirijo a uno u otro componente y necesito pasar el objeto seleccionado arriba. Sin embargo lo más que consigo es recibir un literal "[Object object]

HTML

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let visit of list">
    <span (click)="selected(visit.id)">
      <span class="photo">{{ visit.urlFoto }}</span>
      <span id="text-data">
        <span>{{ visit.cliente.nombre }} {{ visit.cliente.apellidos }}</span>
        <span>{{ visit.cliente.apellido2}}</span>
      </span> 
    </span>    
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">   
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['client']" [queryParams]="{'p': this.index - 1, 'list': this.listVisits[this.index - 1]}">Client Detail</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

TS del componente client:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.routeParams.queryParams.subscribe( params => {
      this.index = params['p'];
      this.listVisits = params['list'];
      console.log(this.listVisits); 
    })
  }
```

Comment: Buenas, no creo que sea buena idea pasar un objeto como parámetro. Pasaría el Id del objeto que quieras obtener y luego realizaría una llamada al servicio para obtener ese objeto pasando como parametro el Id. Creo que sería una mejor solución.

Comment: Mmm... precisamente quería ahorrarme esa segunda llamada pero sí, tiene pinta de que no va a haber otra opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede,los parámetros se recogen de la URL, por lo que siempre son texto. Podrías usar `JSON.stringify`, pero realmente no es una buena idea.

Lo ideal en ese caso es tener un servicio que comunique a distintos componentes o usar algo como `localStorage` o `sessionStorage` para guardar datos (En cuyo caso también tendrás que usar `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un servicio e injectarlo en el root o injectadrlo en un modulo que alcance a los componentes que quieres comunicar, luego creas una propiedad en la clase del servicio:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProveedorService {

private raizURL = '';
private endpointURL = '';
private endpointURLobtenercontratos = '';

sharedObjContrato: IAlgunaInterface;
```

Luego en tus componentes inyectas el servicio para cargar el objeto que quieres compartir en la propiedad **sharedObjContrato**:

```
 recibos: IAlgunaInterface[] = [];

 constructor(private router: Router, private proveservis: ProveedorService) { }

 ngOnInit() {}

 irDetalle(objRecibo: IAlgunaInterface) {
  this.proveservis.sharedObjContrato = objRecibo;
  this.router.navigate(['ruta/ruta2']);
 }



export class RecibodetalleComponent implements OnInit {

objRecibo: IAlgunaInterface;

constructor(private proveservis: ProveedorService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.objRecibo = this.proveservis.sharedObjCOntrato;      
   }

}
```